# How to update data in table?

Tags: java

I finished making an encryption program that encrypts text and tried to  apply this program to encrypt a field in a database table. I have a problem  that all the data field is encrypted by on value (last record)

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    String v_url = "jdbc:oracle:thin:@192.168.2.154:1522:orcl2";
    String v_username = "scott";
    String v_password = "tiger";
    Connection con = null;
    try {
        DriverManager.registerDriver(new oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver());
        con = DriverManager.getConnection(v_url, v_username, v_password);
        System.out
                .println("Connection to Oracle database  was Established");
        String sql = "select JOB_NAME  from job  ";
        Statement stmt = con.createStatement();
        ResultSet srs = stmt.executeQuery(sql);
        while (srs.next()) {
            vname = srs.getString("job_name");
        }
    } catch (SQLException err) {
        System.out.println(err.getMessage());
    }
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Enter Your KeyText ");
    String StrKey = in.nextLine();
    // Print the Concatenated Data.

    String ConcatenatedData = StrKey.concat(vname);
    System.out.println("The plaintext Data is : " + ConcatenatedData);

    // Convering the Concatenated data to Ascii data.
    byte[] asciiText = null;
    try {
        // translating text String to 7 bit ASCII encoding
        asciiText = ConcatenatedData.getBytes("US-ASCII");
        // System.out.println(Arrays.toString(asciiText));
    } catch (java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    String binary = "";
    for (byte b : asciiText) {
        // binary = Integer.toBinaryString(b & 255 | 256).substring(1);
        binary += Integer.toBinaryString(0x100 + (int) (b & 0xFF)).substring(1);
    }
    // System.out.println("Requested binary :" +binary);
    String ReversedBinary = binary.replace('0', '2').replace('1', '0').replace('2', '1');
    // System.out.println("Reveresd binary :" + ReversedBinary);
    mainencdec decimalToBinary = new mainencdec();
    String binary1 = decimalToBinary.convertBinaryStringToString(ReversedBinary);

    try {
        String sql_statment = "UPDATE job  SET job_name =?";
        PreparedStatement updatequery = con.prepareStatement(sql_statment);
        updatequery.setString(1, binary1);
        updatequery.executeQuery();
        con.commit();
        System.out.println("An existing user was updated successfully!");
    } catch (SQLException err) {
        System.out.println(err.getMessage());
    }

}
```

the problem is that the data in job name field is encrypted by the same value as:               `JOB_NAME`

```
323130,2'2$1'2&0&2#1
323130,2'2$1'2&0&2#1
323130,2'2$1'2&0&2#1
323130,2'2$1'2&0&2#1
323130,2'2$1'2&0&2#1
```

I want each value in this field encrypted according to its data

Comment: Please fully explain your problem and write a clear question. I have no idea what you're asking.

Comment: I updated my question>

Comment: are you storing the encrypting key in the same encryted value ?

Comment: yes, firstly i concate the key with the data in the field(name) , then i made many operation on these concatenated data to be encrypted, lastly i want to store these encrypted data in table, but i found that these data is encrypted by the same value